# Will HFS+ extended attributes be lost on FreeNAS?

Tags: time-machine, hfs+, extended-attributes, freenas

I have FreeNAS server partially set up on an HP Microserver, but just realized that I may lose all my extended attribute metadata on the files that come from my Macs (which is what most of my computers are).  This metadata is somewhat important to me, so if FreeNAS will lose this data then maybe I need to rethink my strategy.

I was going to use FreeNAS for both Time Machine backup and as a file server, so the metadata would be relevant in both cases.

Will FreeNAS keep the metadata if I connect to it using AFP, or will it lose the metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeNAS supports the creation of AFP file shares for general use with OS X systems. For Time Machine backups, you need to make sure to specifically enable Time Machine support (Disk Discovery enabled and type set to Time Machine) on a particular AFP share you intend to use.

Further clarification:  AFP currently supports Unicode file names, POSIX and access control list permissions, resource forks, named extended attributes, and advanced file locking.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol

Comment: AFP can be used to export HFS+, NFS and UFS mounts. As such, it should have no issue with extended attributes (which is just the Tiger-and-later extension of resource forks).

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your concerns.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think it can also support ZFS on FreeNAS...

Comment: In the context of the question, ZFS support on FreeNAS is not equivalent to HFS+/AFP support. Moreover, to support Time Machine backups, AFP _must_ be used; it is not optional.

Comment: Are you saying that if my disks use ZFS then I can't share files with AFP?  Or that the AFP support would degrade if the file system is ZFS?

Comment: No, I'm saying that regardless of what file system is used, AFP is the access protocol required. It's safe to say that any device that safely supports Time Machine backups will have no issue with standard data.

Comment: It would not surprise me if a non-Apple system that claimed to support AFP & Time Machine (and mostly did so) did not actually save rarely-used meta-data.  (How many people actually add their own extended attributes to files?)

Comment: An interesting point. Since you're concerned (and correctly so), you might wish to ask the question on a FreeNAS-specific list or IRC channel. I doubt there's an issue, but discussing it with the FreeNAS people directly seems advisable.